# Brace initialisation of vector of variant containing unique_ptr

Tags: c++, stl, variant

Why does the following code compile when using `std::array` but not when using `std::vector`:

```
using varianttypes = std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>;
std::array<varianttypes, 4> a{1, 2.2, 3, 4.3}; // compiles fine
std::vector<varianttypes> a{1, 2.2, 3, 4.3}; // gives an error
```

I get this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator_traits.h:298:9: error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at'
        _VSTD::construct_at(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:858:15: note: expanded from macro '_VSTD'
#define _VSTD std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:750:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>>>::construct<std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>, const std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>> &, void, void>' requested here
        _Traits::construct(__a, _VSTD::__to_address(__begin2), *__begin1);
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:1099:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__construct_range_forward<std::allocator<std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>>, const std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>> *, std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>> *>' requested here
    _VSTD::__construct_range_forward(this->__alloc(), __first, __last, __tx.__pos_);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:1357:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>>::__construct_at_end<const std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>> *>' requested here
        __construct_at_end(__il.begin(), __il.end(), __il.size());
        ^
variantstuff.cpp:82:29: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>>::vector' requested here
  std::vector<varianttypes> a{1, 2.2, 3, 4.3};
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/construct_at.h:35:16: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>, _Args = <const std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>> &>]: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::variant<int, double, std::unique_ptr<double>>'
constexpr _Tp* construct_at(_Tp* __location, _Args&& ...__args) {
               ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [variantstuff.o] Error 1
```

Comment: "Gives an error" whats the error?

Comment: You cannot move out of an `initializer_list`, only copy; and `unique_ptr` (and consequently the `variant` potentially containing one) can only be moved, not copied. No `initializer_list` is involved with the `array` (that's aggregate initialization, which is only superficially similar).